# Changing an imageview as a subview from one imageview to anotherone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, superview

I am creating an app, in which I have two small imageview (using have of screen each)
One of this views has a uiimageview as a subview, I need to change this view to be a subview of the otherImageView, after I drag it to it, I'm using removeFromSuperview: & addSubview: methods, but the problem is that the reference of the position is the first imageView, that is why I'm having problems positioning the imageview in the new superview...
Is there a better way to do this?
I hope this is understandable, if I need to put some code, let me know.
Thank you so much

Edit: I'm adding some code that I'm using

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

startPoint_ = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
CGPoint newPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
CGRect frm = [self frame];
newPoint.x -= startPoint_.x;
newPoint.y -= startPoint_.y;

frm.origin = newPoint;
currentPoint_.x = frm.origin.x;
currentPoint_.y = frm.origin.y;

}
```

In the second line of this code I'm locating the view en self.superview (the origin superview). In order to manage better the position, could be a good idea to change this location to self.superview.superview (that is containing both views). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand the details of your question; anyway if I correctly interpret the sentence:

> the problem is that the reference of the position is the first imageView, that is why i'm having problems positioning the imageview in the new superview

I think you should set the `frame` property of the `UIImageView` you move so that it appears in the proper location in the destination superview.

Apart from that, removing and then adding as a subview seems the correct approach to me. If this reply does not help, you could try and post some code and possibly some snapshots to make your point more evident.